# Correct way to set optional Django field to blank?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

If you have an optional Django model field, what is the correct way to create that Django object when the user leaves the form field blank?  I have the following model and form (By the way, I know I could use a ModelForm):

```
# models.py
class Club(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    co_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

# forms.py
class ClubForm(forms.Form):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    co_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=128, required=False)
```

If the user leaves the co-host field blank, should I enter a blank as shown below when I create the object?  I've been under the impression that if you're inserting a blank into your database table, you're still giving it a value which you may not want to do.  What's the correct way to handle this situation?  Thanks.

```
# views.py
club = Club.objects.create(
    hostname = form.cleaned_data['hostname'],
    co_hostname = ''
    )
```

Comment: With `null=True`, you now have two "empty" values for your charfield: `None` and `''`. It's generally recommended to not use `null=True` on a charfield unless you need it for some reason (e.g. a unique index).

Comment: Thanks.  For the benefit of other readers, what you're saying is explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may pass `None` as the field value because your field has the attribute `null` set to `True`.

So you can have:

```
club = Club.objects.create(hostname=form.cleaned_data['hostname'], co_hostname=None)
```

To make your life easier, I would also suggest using [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) for your forms since you are copying the exact same fields from your model to your form.

Comment: What about if you have `blank=True` instead of `null=True`?

Comment: @Boris With `blank=True`, you can leave empty fields in your forms. So this attribute is more related to form validation. As an example, you could apply an empty string to your field like `YourModel.objects.create(your_field='')`.